# Wget Intallation in Cygwin

Tags: installation, cygwin, wget

I tried to install wget version-1.14 (tar.xz package) on cygwin, but it failed.
My steps were

```
tar -xf wget-1.14.tar.xz
cd wget-1.14
./configure
```

After some time, it spits a configure error.

How to install wget in cygwin under Windows 7, then?

Comment: Could you give us the error it gave?

Comment: upvoting post since you get douche bags on superuser that downvote for either no apparent reason or downvote since they know and would rather not share the answer/solution

Answer (score 7):

A little bit late..but a lot has changed since:

(Win7)

1. make sure you have the latest installer - `setup-x86_64.exe`,
   if not, dowload the latest here [cygwin.com](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html)
2. run the exe file you downloaded
3. Installation process definitions (walk-through):

   - install from internet
   - Root Directory (if you had previous installation, keep the same path)
   - All Users (Recommended)
   - Local Package Directory (if you had previous installation, keep the same path)
   - choose connection type - usually 'direct'
   - choose download site
   - at this stage it will download a setup package
   - choose additional packages by clicking 'View' drop-down as 'Not installed'
   - 'Search' text-box type 'wget'
   - change 'skip' by clicking the icon next to it and it will display the version umber to be installed and the 'Bin' check box will be checked
   - check the 'Src?' check box if you wish to get the source code as well
   - click next after choosing all the new packages to be installed
4. be patient as it might take some time....

good luck

Answer (score 3):

`wget` is also available as a Cygwin package, so you could just install it using the Cygwin installer. As of this writing, the latest version available is wget-1.13.4.

If you just want to use wget, using the Cygwin package is easier than compiling it yourself.
However, compiling from source should also work. If `configure` complains, then most likely some dependency (such as a library) is missing.

Comment: Yes I installed it as a cygwin package, It is working Problem solved
Many Thanks wingedsubmariner and sleske

Answer (score 0):

You could use [gnuwin](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) too.
It works fine, in cygwin and on basic windows cmd.